# Redirect category from one store view to another

Tags: url, redirect

I have a trouble with my subdomain and have therefore deactivated a store view.
Is it possible to redirect the categories from that store view to the main store view?
The direct of a category is already used to create the semantic URL.
The URL i want to redirect is da.domain.com/tuborg/tuborg-bar-items.html
It should be redirected to domain.com/tuborg/tuborg-bar-items.html
The category ID is 25

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom redirect with the store view code in it instead of the subdomain probably.

Something like tuborg/tuborg-bar-items.html -> tuborg/tuborg-bar-items.html?___store=storeview_code in

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, after trying everything listed above and on several other SO answers 
i discovered there is more than one base_url definition in the core_config_data table

if you run

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%'
```

You should see all of the definitions
the scope was different on this definition and was overriding the default which i had already changed.